# My python code does not run a print statement at the end of a loop

Tags: python

I have this problem when i run the program it all goes good an all, but when a user gets the right answer, the code does not print neither print("Good Job!") or print("Correct"). what is wrong with the code ?

```
import random

firstNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
secondNumber = random.randint(1, 50)
result = firstNumber + secondNumber
result = int(result)
print("Hello ! What\'s your name ? ")
name = input()
print("Hello !"+" "+ name)
print("Ok !"+" "+ name +" "+ "let\'s start !")
print("What is"+ " " + str(firstNumber) +"+"+ str(secondNumber))
userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
while (userAnswer != result) :
    if (userAnswer > result) :
        print("Wrong")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
    userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
    if (userAnswer == result):
        print("Correct")
        print("Good Job!")
        break
input("\n\n Press to exit")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that your while-loop will only run as long as the first answer is wrong. Everything that is indented after `while (userAnswer != result)` will be ignored by Python if the first answer is right. So logically a first correct answer can never reach `print("Correct")`, since that would require the answer to be both wrong (to start the while loop) and right (to get to "Correct").

One option is to get rid of the while-loop, and just use if's. You get two chances this way, then you lose.

```
if (userAnswer == result):
    print("Well done!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
    userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
    if (userAnswer == result):
        print("Correct")
        print("Good Job!")
    else:
        print("Nope all wrong you lose")
```

Another option is to make an infinite loop using While. (like @csharpcoder said)

```
while (True) :
    userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
    if (userAnswer == result):
        print("Correct")
        print("Good Job!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong answer")
```

In the last option a wrong answer gets "Wrong answer" and the while-loop starts again, since `True` is of course still True. So you try again, until you get the right answer, which will bring you to "correct, good job" and then break (which stops the loop).

I struggled with while-loops and kind of getting it in my head that indentation means Python will treat it as 'one thing' and skip it all if I start it with something that's False.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It explains the problem clearly and shows ways of solving it.

Answer (score 3):

If the answer is correct, then

```
while (userAnswer != result) :
```

will cause the loop contents to be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a infinite while loop something like this :

```
while (True) :
    userAnswer = int(input("Your answer : "))
    if (userAnswer == result):
        print("Correct")
        print("Good Job!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Wrong answer")
```

In your logic if you enter the wrong answer first time and correct answer afterwards , then it will work as per your requirement , but if you enter the correct answer first time it will simple skip the while loop .

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you get input *outside* of your loop and then don't do anything with it. If your answer is correct on the first try, you will get no output because `userAnswer != result` will be `False` immediately and your `while` loop won't run.

Some other points:

```
if (userAnswer > result) :
    print("Wrong")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

is redundant because you are guaranteed to fall into one of these, as you will only get here if the answer is wrong (and therefore `>` or `< result`). Just print `"Wrong"` without a condition, as the only reason this would run is if the answer was wrong.

```
print("Correct")
print("Good Job!")
```

You can use `\n` to print on a new line instead of having multiple `print` statements together. Usually you only use multiple `print`s together for readability, but `print("Correct\nGood job!")` isn't that much less readable.

```
if (userAnswer == result):
    #...
    break
```

You don't need `break` here because the answer is already correct and the loop won't repeat anyway.

```
print("Hello !"+" "+ name)
print("Ok !"+" "+ name +" "+ "let\'s start !")
print("What is"+ " " + str(firstNumber) +"+"+ str(secondNumber))
```

Here, you append string literals to string literals (`"Hello!" + " "`). You don't need to do that as you can just write `"Hello! "`.

```
result = firstNumber + secondNumber
result = int(result)
```

The result (pun not intended) is already an integer, so you don't need to convert it.

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit to refactor, in an attempt to make it more clear:

```
import random


name = input("Hello ! What's your name? ")
print("Hello, {name}!".format(name=name))
print("Ok, {name}, let's start!".format(name=name))

first_number = random.randint(1, 50)
second_number = random.randint(1, 50)
correct_answer = first_number + second_number
print("What is, '{first} + {second}'?".format(first=first_number,
                                              second=second_number))
user_answer = None
while user_answer != correct_answer:
    try:
        user_answer = int(input("Your answer : "))  # ValueError will be raised if non integer value given
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input!")
        user_answer = None
    if user_answer:
        if user_answer == correct_answer:
            print("Correct")
            print("Good Job!")
        else:
            print('--> Wrong, try again!')
input("\n<< Press any key to exit >>")
```